# Swift perform segue without clicking button

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm making a small game in SpriteKit where I have a bool value stored that checks if it's the first time the user plays my game. If it is, I want the app to redirect him to another viewcontroller where he enters his character-name.

However, I'm having trouble getting my app to do so.

In my "GameViewController.swift" I have this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    checkGame()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

func checkGame() {
    //Check game
    let firstPlay:Bool = appData.bool(forKey: "\(GameData.firstPlay)")
    print(firstPlay)

    if firstPlay == false {
        print("Heading for setup")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToSetup", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

However, the "setup viewcontroller" isn't loaded. I can manage to tricker the segue with a button-click, but that's not what I want. I want it to happen as soon as the view is loaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you meant by "setup viewcontroller" isn't loaded", but usually we don't perform segues in the `viewDidLoad`. At this time, the view has just been loaded into memory and has not appeared yet. Performing a segue at this time is kind of a weird thing to do.

I recommend you to perform the segue in `viewDidAppear()`:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated: animated)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToSetup", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically call a segue with the following:

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueId", sender: self);
```

Answer (score -1):

As it was said, in viewDidLoad stage UIViewController can't be done any UI-interaction, and performSegue to, because view is not at the view hierarchy yet. You can do this at `viewDidAppear(animated:Bool)`.

Comment: What does this add to Sweeper's answer? It's really an "I agree" comment on the existing answer since it doesn't provide any additional information.